# SlidingMenu (com.slidingmenu.lib ) in Android

Tags: android, slidingmenu

i am using com.slidingmenu.lib in my project. Currently i want to open and close my menu on one Button click. But in libary they are taking event on complete layout. i dont understand how can avoid click event on complete layout and just add same event on single button click.

I am using following code in my activity.

```java
 menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
        menu.setFadeEnabled(false);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `toggle()` method to handle this type of situation:

```java
btOpenCloseMenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        menu.toggle(true);

    }
});
```